# Passing a function as argument through two functions that is a public member of a class

Tags: c++, functional-programming

I have a public member function that needs to be passed as an argument to a function that is below the function I need to initiate the calculation from. Additionally the function that needs to be passed has arguments required.  I am working in c++ and this is my first large coding project and am having trouble diagnosing the compilation error.

Note I am trying to avoid using pointers, this is not my choice but (edited) my bosses therefore everything is by reference.

```cpp
-----------------------------------------------------------------
class Class1 {
    public:
        void get_val(int &a, double &val) ;
    private:
        vector<double> vector_ ;
} ; 
  void Class1::get_val(int &a, double &val) { vector_[a] = val;}
-----------------------------------------------------------------
class Class2 {
    public:
        void calc_func(int &b, 
                       std::function< void ( int, double) > functocall, 
                       double &ans)
    private:
        int conversion_ ;
        void calc_other_func(int &c, 
                             std::function< void ( int, double) > functocall, 
                             double &ans)
} ; 

void Class2::calc_func(int &b, 
                       std::function< void ( int, double) > functocall, 
                       double &ans)
 { 
     int c = b * 2 ;
     double tmp_val ;
     calc_other_func(c,functocall, tmp_val) ;
     ans = tmp_val / 4 ;
 }

void Class2::calc_other_func(int &c, 
                             std::function< void ( int, double) > functocall, 
                             double &ans) 
{
    int d;
    double val;
    d = c / conversion_ ;
    functocall(d, val) ;
    ans = val;
}
-----------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    int b = 4;
    double ans;
    Class2.calc_func(b,Class1.get_val(int, double),ans) ;
}
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The compilation error I get is:

"In member function void Class2::calc_func(int&, double&):
 error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
 Class1.get_val(int,double),"

Comment: Let an instance of Class2 call the member function `calc_func` . Else  declare calc_func as static function.

Comment: Btw.: `Class1::get_val()` has arguments `int&, double&` but `functocall` requires signature `int, double`. That's a difference -> references vs. values.

Comment: First of all it looks like you used to Java or some similar language, in C++ when accessing class function `::` used instead of `.`. Second, when passing function you don't need to specify it's arguments or argument types. Third, you probably need to use `std::bind` to bind function to particular instance, if it is not static of course. It would be helpful if you provided minimal reproducible example (i.e. do not remove class declarations).

Comment: @Scheff so I tried changing the signatures but I received the following error "error: no match for call to ‘(std::function<void(int&, int&, double&)>) (int&, const int&, double&)'"

Comment: @sklott I have no experience with Java, just Python and Fortran90. I edited my example to add further detail as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, like in Python, you need to instantiate objects when calling instance methods, as opposed to class (`static` in C++ terms) methods.

After fixing few syntax issues with you code I tried to use `std::bind`, but it didn't work, since it return type incompatible with `std::function`.

So, I think the only simple way left is to use lambda, i.e. something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int b = 4;
    double ans;
    Class1 c1;
    Class2 c2;
    c2.calc_func(b, [&c1](int i, double d) {c1.get_val(i, d);}, ans);
}
```

Or you can pass non-member function, possibly wrapping access to member function, i.e.:

```
Class1 c1;

void get_c1_val(int i, double d)
{
    c1.get_val(i, d);
}

int main()
{
    int b = 4;
    double ans;
    Class2 c2;
    c2.calc_func(b, get_c1_val, ans);
}
```

PS: Theoretically you can use `std::mem_fn` instead of `std::function` and pass reference to `get_val` directly, but it looks like old templates like this gets deprecated with time, so I wouldn't use them...